# Group by different time frames

Tags: looker-studio

How can I add different time frames to a single table?

Google Sheet to dataset: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YFSeVxq2yei_jOWqd-xxVTCdScgHotE_ocZfSmv6vZA/edit?usp=sharing

Data Studio: https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/d9f750a0-0437-477a-a1fa-e9eb7dc81aa1

I am working with an example dataset linked above that I want to aggregate by multiple timeframes. I want to aggregate the date by year-to-date, month-to-date, quarter-to-date and week-to-date so I can compare the different timeframes in a single table as in the screenshot below. The dataset has two columns, `date` and `demand`.

I tried to use the following CASE WHEN function:

```
CASE
  WHEN WEEK(date) = WEEK(CURRENT_DATE()) AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) THEN "WTD"
  WHEN MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) THEN "MTD"
  WHEN QUARTER(date) = QUARTER(CURRENT_DATE()) AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) THEN "QTD"
  WHEN YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) THEN "YTD"
  ELSE "NAN"
END
```

The issue is that the conditional function above sums up the demand by the first available timeframe first and does not add it to the other timeframes.

For instance, as of today (2022-03-16, yyyy-mm-dd), the first group WTD is correct. However, in March as of today there are 16 days so the `MTD`group should be 16 as demand.

Instead `MTD`is 13. I believe the value is from 16 minus `WTD` which is 3 and as a result it is 16-3=13.

How can I group metrics by different timeframes that I calculate?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You've done it all almost
(I didn't test it)

select
sum(case WHEN WEEK(date) = WEEK(CURRENT_DATE()) AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) then demand)
end as "WTD",
sum (case when MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())) then demand)
end as "MTD"
-- and so on
from your table

Comment: Could you provide proof of a working solution by using the Google Data Studio Report provided in the question? The proposed solution currently looks like it's designed for BigQuery (indicated by the use of `select`) and not for Google Data Studio (the question is specifically about looking for a Google Data Studio solution, which currently does not support `select`)